# jQuery regex match returning empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to strip out the IDs of embedded youtube videos, so I  have the url which is something like:

```
www.youtube.com/embed/[someID]&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&frameborder=1&modestbranding=1
```

All I want is the [someID] string. I have declared an empty array to store the regex matches;

```
var videoID = [];
```

The closest I have come to a solution is:

```
videoID = videoID.match("embed/(\w*)");
```

but this results in the following:

```
video[0] ("embed/")
video[1] ()
```

Comment: jQuery isn't a language. You're writing JavaScript. JS doesn't have any builtin URL parsing capabilities, so you'll have to do some sort of string manipulations: `url.split('&')[0].split('/').slice(-1)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
url = "www.youtube.com/embed/someID&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&frameborder=1&modestbranding=1";
```

Then use either:

```
var videoID = url.match(/embed\/(\w*)/); // regex
```

OR else:

```
var videoID = url.match("embed/\\w*)"); // regex object
```

Both will give this **output**:

```
["embed/someID", "someID"]
```

If you provide a string then `String#match` method will attempt to construct a `RegExp` object and for that case you need to use `\\w` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you may get id. I didn't use regex but still we can get id from above demo like urls.

```
var url ="www.youtube.com/embed/[someID]&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&frameborder=1&modestbranding=1";

var urlQueries = url.split('/'); 
var queryParameters = urlQueries[2].split('&'); // arrays of all query parameters
var id = queryParameters[0]; // get ids at index 0
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eJdH2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) can do Positive-Lookbehinds, but try this `(?<=embed\/)([^&]*)`

If not, then `(?:embed\/)([^&]*)` is closer to your example.

---

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/nW5uL8